# How can I convert the text from a /title to a /tellraw?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to convert a `/title` text into a `/tellraw`. How can I do this?

Command:

```
/title @a actionbar [{"color":"yellow","text":" "},{"color":"none","selector":"@a[score_playerKill_min=1]"},{"color":"white","text":" has just killed "},{"color":"yellow","text":""},{"color":"none","selector":"@a[score_playerDeath_min=1]"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`/tellraw` uses the same JSON text component format as `/title`, so you should just be able to do:

```
/tellraw @a [{"color":"yellow","text":" "},{"color":"none","selector":"@a[score_playerKill_min=1]"},{"color":"white","text":" has just killed "},{"color":"yellow","text":""},{"color":"none","selector":"@a[score_playerDeath_min=1]"}]
```